# Как определить predicate на методе класса?

Tags: typescript

Речь о [typescript predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) и неверном поведении типов в некоторых встроенных объектах JS.

Если самостоятельно определить predicate, TypeScript "помнит" о каком типе идет речь и соответственно не вызывает ошибок ...

```
const isString = (s: unknown): s is string => typeof s === 'string'
const isBoolString = (s: unknown): boolean => typeof s === 'string'

function foo(something: unknown) {
  if (isString(something)) something.replace('a', '')
  if (isBoolString(something)) something.replace('a', '')
  // "Правильная" ошибка ----- ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

... но вариант с методами экземпляров, например с `Map<K, V>`, определенный по умолчанию в "lib.es2015.collection.d.ts", не "помнит" что строкой выше мы уже удостоверились в наличии свойства и вызов `Map.get()` не должен возвращать `undefined`:

```
function bar<K, V>(key: K, map: Map<K, V>): V | 123 {
  if (map.has(key)) {
    return map.get(key) // V | undefined
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
  return 123
}
```

Хотелось бы переопределить некоторые типы, т.е. должно получится что-то вроде такого:

```
interface Map<K, V> {
  has(key: K): false | is V
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=11&pc=41#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-akkToEhxynS45nWMgHGWCdQAZYdliHUcDOnRFJ1AAAfUB72vABmfljSoEUjKIVoWTofptN02VnKkIUhXIBgVhITF3LYjidIcOU5Cs2y1mk2TenkwKgrkVMsuy41M3SkKwsxeyHIzIA)

И ваши варианты с методами кастомного класса...

Comment: проблема в том, что map.get и map.has никак не связаны на уровне типов. При этом, можно сделать, чтобы has был ` typescript predicate` для всего `map`, и тип даже определяется несколько перегрузок для `get` внутри `if`, но выбирает почему-то начальную с `V|undefined`

Comment: @Grundy Что-то не выходит придумать вариант, когда заранее неизвестен тип ключа.
С константными значениями работает. Глянь ниже, может будут какие мысли...

Answer (score 0):

Такой метод определения predicate не желает работать с "переменной типа"

```
interface Map<K, V> {
  // Извлекаем тип
  has<T extends K>(key: T): this is (
    // Извлекаем метод
    Omit<Map<K, V>, 'get'> &
    { // Переопределяем на момент вызова "predicate | has"
      get<R extends K>(k: R):
        // При вызове get(), проверяем ранее извлеченный тип T
        R extends T ? V : (V | undefined)
    }
  )
  get(key: K): V | undefined
}
```

Вариант ниже работает

```
const map = new Map<string, number>()

const v1 = map.get('key') // number | undefined

if (map.has('key')) {
  // Оба варианта работают как и ожидается
  const v2 = map.get('key')   // number
  const v3 = map.get('error') // number | undefined
}
```

... но если тип заранее неизвестен, опять ошибка

```
function foo<K, V>(key: K, m: Map<K, V>): V | 123 {
  if (m.has(key)) {
    return m.get(key)
    // error ^^^^^^^^
  }
  return 123
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-6HAA6HGrSpVVYNZFJ1PpkXiyXSsNG01sCydAN0UspVKlSvVGu1-wq5GAPBBRPcvtbbfdnRJIIA5EGeMWgoHRsHtlEwUjQMmoiS9Pr9eYATMWe+W1UPq7WemB62mGMec2eAMxXssV9MMT0MDWdbJi+TZ6gabbGu6ZpgKWcECLAoAoDIJDooyoBhFaNooEIggUhEyFoBQ7h4NQaCADIgOCABIglCiDE0EWBKHA8Gw3qgBYnqei47jeOqtTFO4Ux1NGSzeNqQqigW55fmOgSdt2fZpHxDSjuMzA8GKDAmP6N48Mp4zBH+AGgAAemZ5lmYkJqBOpmnaVJH7GkAA)

Comment: если `(V | undefined)` на `never` заменить, ошибка пропадает, но и типы других ключей never становятся внутри

Comment: @Grundy В том то и дело, что `has` становится бесполезным, и другой ключ не вызовет ошибку

Comment: Проблема в том что выходит `K extends K` - что-то непонятно пока как проверить именно на совпадение типов